# Populate a Contacts List from a people picker through custom webpart (SP2010)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, people-picker

So this is the goal, for a user to add people to the OOB Contacts List Template through a people picker. Has anyone done this or have any suggestions on how to accomplish this task? InfoPath is not an option.

My current thought is to iterate through the people entered in the picker after a button is pressed. Then take the text and find the SPUser that the name belongs to. This would give access to the individuals’ information that could then be put into the list one field at a time. I would think that there would be a better way to do it but maybe not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thanks for all the help people! :P

This was not all that easy because of all the issues with the User Profile Service. Unfortunately this seems to be the only solution.